# Childbrowser save web address on home button

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use the latest xcode, childbrowser, and cordova version.

Is there a way to save the last visited page from childbrowser when I press the home button on my cell phone?

I need to save it because when I resume to my app, I need to check first if the user is still authenticated or do an autologin again. Thanks for advice or solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser/ChildBrowser.js) supports a callback for `locationChange`. You can use this to save every time URL changes. App doesn't get any callbacks when Home button is pressed.